# Disable browser bar from reopening on mobile file input

Tags: javascript, html

The goal is to hide on mobile the browser bar.
Since the `minimal-ui` stopped working, and after reading tones of information , it seems there is no solution.

One thing people do on load  is :

```
scrollTop(1,1);
```

Which seems not to work *unless the user scroll by himself* ( at least on iPhone `Chrome/Safari`). A programing scrolling will not close it.

A solution I found is to encourage the user to scroll a little, then take control over scrolling by disable/enable it. (After the bar is closed)

The problem with that is that if the user select a file with :

```
<input type="file" id="imageUpload">
```

***then the bar will be open again***.

Is there any solution to these things in 2019 to get a full screen on mobile ?

Comment: Without speaking as to a solution, I can say with confidence that browser vendors disabled the previous functionality for a reason — it's best to avoid doing something like this automatically.

Comment: good reason or not, its ugly and I want to get a better experience for my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Apple specific meta tag indeed facilitates hiding Safari UI components with the modulation that the user has added the web-application onto their home screen.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

The section [Hiding Safari User Interface Components](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and the [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW3) shall dispense you further information on the matter.